# Manage widgets from page edit screen

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to find a way to integrate the widget control area into the page edit screen. For the site I'm making it would be perfect with the same drag and drop functionality.

I want a list of the available widgets that I can drag and drop into the page widget area. The widgets will then only be shown on that particular page.

I've looked through the wp-admin/widgets.php file and tried to use some code from there. I even tried just including widgets.php at the end of the post.php (which is basically what I want, but of course gave me funny results).
Please don't suggest plug-ins like Widget Context or Widget Logic. Those are my fallback if I cant do this :)

So I would like ideas and/or input on how to accomplish this. Preferably I'd like to do it in the functions.php file, or in a plug-in.

Edit: I'm still interested in this. Just a theoretical description on how to do this would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me apologize in advance, I don't have an answer for you but I do have a plugin suggestion that may be a better fall back than Widget Context or Widget Logic (this one lets you add the widget content from the "post edit" screen):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-snippets/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've played around with that before. Nice plugin. But I need multiple widgets on the page edit screen.

Answer (score 0):

Its a really old question but I don't think that you've got the right answer. I think the following plugin (not free) is closer for what you need. With this plugin you can manage the widgets from the page edit screen. Have fun!

[Ultimate Widget Manager](http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-widget-manager/7601552)